# NullPointerException at setProgressImgView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fatal-error, forceclose

I'm getting a NullPointerException error at line 423:

```
mProgressImageview5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty5);
```

and I'm not sure why. Everything was working fine up until a moment ago and I don't recall changing anything related to this and I've looked it over several times and I'm still unsure why it is happening.

SOURCE:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ImageView mProgressImageview1;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview2;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview3;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview4;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview5;
    public static int count;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    int version;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "STDataSettings";
    private Button mUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private TextView mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    AlertDialog mConfirmAlert = null;
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    public static XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;
    private NetworkTask task;
    private AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation;
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateActivity";
    Context ctx;
    private Button assist_update_btn = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = tm.getNetworkType();
        int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();
        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
                || (phoneType != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE)) {
            // If the phone type is CDMA or
            // the phone phone type is not GSM and the network type is none of
            // the network types indicated in the statement
            // Display incompatibility message
            showAlert(getString(R.string.incomp_sm_dialog));
            // Network type is looked because some tablets have no phone type.
            // We rely on network type in such cases
        } else if(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                || !(tm.getSimOperator().equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo)) 
                        || (tm.getSimOperator().equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))))) {

            // if SIM is present and is NOT a T-Mo network SIM,
            // display Error message alert indicating to use SM SIM
            showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        }// No SIM or SIM with T-Mo MNC MCC present
        else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            // Initial UI setup for versions lower than ICS
            setContentView(R.layout.update);
            mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);

            mUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        } else {// ICS and up


            if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                    .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                task = new NetworkTask();
                task.execute("");
                // Device has T-Mo network SIM card MCC and MNC correctly
                // populated
                // Reduce number of steps to 6
                TotalSteps = 6;
            }

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mUpdateButton) {
            // Update button for versions lower than ICS is selected

            onClickMethod(v);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else

            if (v.getId() == R.id.assist_update_btn) {

                // Update button for ICS and up is selected
                // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
                String text = "";
                CharSequence styledText = text;
                switch (mInstructionNumber) {
                case 0:
                    // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                    // 2nd set of instructions
                    text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                            TotalSteps);
                    styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                    // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                    tv.setText(styledText);
                    // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                    // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                    // button is pressed
                    mInstructionNumber++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                    styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                    tv.setText(styledText);
                    // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                    // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                    // button is pressed
                    mInstructionNumber++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                    setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                    String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                            getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                    styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                    TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                    assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                    mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                    mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                    mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                    mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                }
            } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
                // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
                // up is selected
                // Create ConfigActivity Intent
                Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
                // Invoke ConfigActivity Intent to start the assisted update
                startActivity(i);
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));

            } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {
                // go back to 1st set of instructions if read again is selected
                mInstructionNumber = 0;
                setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
                String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_cta2);
                CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
                TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
                assistText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
                mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
    }

    public void onClickMethod(View v) {
        mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.drawable.btn_update_active_hdpi);

    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                UpdateActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        mConfirmAlert = builder.create();
        mConfirmAlert.show();
    }

    // AsyncTask to call web service
    class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStream> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                // saving the response in InputStream
                stream = getQueryResults("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
                // stream = new BufferedInputStream(https.getInputStream());
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) { // Print the content
                    // on the console
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    in.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // The code below plays a Simple Promo animation

            for (int incr = 0; incr < 2; incr++) {
                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                // Invoke UI to change updating text to show sequential dot loading animation
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full);

                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
            }
            return stream;
        }

        /*
         * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
         * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
         */
        protected synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(String urlQueryString)
                throws IOException, SAXException, SSLException,
                SocketTimeoutException, Exception {

            HttpsURLConnection https = null;
            String uri = urlQueryString;

            URL urlo = new URL(uri);

            try {
                https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
                https.setConnectTimeout(20000); // 20 second timeout
                https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                if ("gzip".equals(https.getContentEncoding())) {
                    stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
                } else
                    stream = https.getInputStream();

            } catch (SSLException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

            }

            return stream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            // Call function to update image view

            setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1], progress[2],
                    progress[3], progress[4]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
            super.onPostExecute(stream);
            // This method is called to parse the response and save the ArrayLists
            success();
            assistUpdate();


        }

    }

    private void assistUpdate() {
        // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
        setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
        assist_update_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
        assist_update_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void setProgressImgView(Integer imageViewId1, Integer imageViewId2,
            Integer imageViewId3, Integer imageViewId4, Integer imageViewId5) {
        // update image view with the updating dots
        // Reset view layout in case orientation while updating
        setContentView(R.layout.updating);

        mProgressImageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
        mProgressImageview1.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId1);
        mProgressImageview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
        mProgressImageview2.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId2);
        mProgressImageview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty3);
        mProgressImageview3.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId3);
        mProgressImageview4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty4);
        mProgressImageview4.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId4);
        mProgressImageview5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty5);
        mProgressImageview5.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId5);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    private void endUpdate(View v) {
        finish();

    }

    public void success() {

        // to parse the response
        try {
            handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // to set method to save the ArryaLists from the parser
        setArrayList();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        // finish();

    }

    // method to save the ArrayLists from parser
    public static void setArrayList() {
        nameArr = handler.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = handler.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = handler.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        portArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        count = handler.getCount();
        // System.out.println("testing123");

        for (int i = 0; i < nameArr.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(nameArr.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ApnArr.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(ApnArr.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
08-21 16:28:17.104: V/STDataSettings(1316): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 16:28:17.104: W/System.err(1316): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 16:28:17.104: W/System.err(1316):     at java.io.FilterInputStream.available(FilterInputStream.java:53)
08-21 16:28:17.104: W/System.err(1316):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:234)
08-21 16:28:17.104: W/System.err(1316):     at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
08-21 16:28:17.104: W/System.err(1316):     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:354)
08-21 16:28:17.114: W/System.err(1316):     at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.doInBackground(UpdateActivity.java:258)
08-21 16:28:17.124: W/System.err(1316):     at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.doInBackground(UpdateActivity.java:1)
08-21 16:28:17.124: W/System.err(1316):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-21 16:28:17.124: W/System.err(1316):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-21 16:28:17.134: W/System.err(1316):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-21 16:28:17.134: W/System.err(1316):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-21 16:28:17.134: W/System.err(1316):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-21 16:28:17.144: W/System.err(1316):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-21 16:28:17.176: D/AndroidRuntime(1316): Shutting down VM
08-21 16:28:17.176: W/dalvikvm(1316): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity.setProgressImgView(UpdateActivity.java:423)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity.access$0(UpdateActivity.java:409)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onProgressUpdate(UpdateActivity.java:384)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onProgressUpdate(UpdateActivity.java:1)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-21 16:28:17.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1316):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 16:2
```

8:20.124: I/Process(1316): Sending signal. PID: 1316 SIG: 9

Comment: make sure ur id is correct..clean once and rerun again

Comment: debuggers are your friends

Comment: Looks like you are trying to cast a TextView to ImageView.Post your xml too please!

Comment: If you've recently changed the XML, a clean build should help. The `R.id` class gets generated fresh that way, so everything is in its proper order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure R.id.loading_empty5 is an imageview and not a textview, then clean the proyect sometimes eclipse mess the reference force rebuild cleaning up the proyect

proyect >> clean >>  and select your proyect name

Answer (score 1):

The `ClassCastException` is because `R.id.loading_empty5` is the ID of a `TextView` which cannot be cast to a `ImageView`.

The `NullPointerException` is unrelated to that. It's coming from your `NetworkTask` class. You're going to have to get in the debugger to figure out why. Possibly GetQueryResults is returning a null?